# MapStruct map Set<Dto> to Set<Enum>

Tags: java, enums, mapstruct

I want to convert UserDto to User

UserDto:

```
public class UserDto {
   private String username;
   private String password;
   private Set<RoleDto> roles;
   //getters and setters
}
```

RoleDto:

```
public class RoleDto {
   private String name;
   //getters and setters
}
```

User:

```
public class User {
   private String username;
   private String password;
   private Set<Role>;
   //getters and setters
}
```

Role:

```
public enum Role {
   private String name;
   //getters
}
```

My mapper class:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper {
    UserDto toDto(User user);
    User fromDto(UserDto userDto); //error here
}
```

But after `maven install` i had problem:

```
Error: java: Role does not have an accessible parameterless constructor.
```

Because Role is enum, I can't create public constructor.
I tried use:

```
@Mapping(source = "roles", targer = "roles")
User fromDto(UserDto userDto);
```

And

```
@Mapping(source = "userDto.roles", targer = "user.roles")
User fromDto(UserDto userDto);
```

But it had no effect. How can i fix it?

Comment: You can't dynamically create enum values I don't think. So either you need to map your RoleDto values to existing Role values, or you need to make Role not an enum if you need to create new Roles dynamically.

Comment: It is possible to map from a `String` to an `Enum`, see https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#_mapping_enum_to_string_or_string_to_enum  Generally speaking, roles are not something you want to create dynamically since the will be well-defined in a system in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I took the advice of @Rup and modified my Role class to:

```
public class Role {
   private String name;
   // getters and setters
}
```